# Is it possible to print to a Star Micronics thermal printer using the JS IPP library?

Tags: electron, thermal-printer

I'm currently working on a project where I need to print receipts from an electron application directly to a Star Micronics thermal printer. I'm considering using the JavaScript Implementation of the Internet Printing Protocol (JS IPP) for this purpose as its the only thing that has actually worked in triggering any actions from the printer over usb, but I'm not sure how to format the receipt like other reciepts.

i've tried using the "node-thermal-printer" package but could not get a response from the printer, not sure if it had anything to do with how i was trying to connect, i couldn't use the Ipp uri

Comment: Your question lacks specific information, so it will be difficult to get advice or answers. How about contacting the vendor's developer support page? [Global Support Center Developers](https://starmicronics.com/support/star-micronics-developers/)